# Chinese Patent Law - what are the official fees, especially annual renewal fees?

Tags: fees, china, chinese-patent

1. Are there any official annual fees to maintain the patent right in China? If yes - what are they?
2. How much does it **approximately** cost to get your patent drafted and submitted for application via the PCT route (officials fees, attorney fees, etc.) in China? Simple static mechanical device (no moving parts).
3. How expensive is it to enforce your patent rights in China via courts?

Comment: One very easy part of the answer - Google "china patent fees wipo" to get the official table of all fees China imposes starting with entering the national stage from a PCT application.Renewals go up as the years past. At the 7 year point it is about $300. Are you in the U.S.?

Comment: 2.: If you start in Europe for example, you can pay like 5k Euros for dafting and another 3k or so for a translation into Chinese. 3: I don't know about China, but, again, Europe, you'd pay a six figure sum - at least, if you got to court.

Comment: It is probably much cheaper to initially draft it (in English) with a Chinese attorney and then translate to Chinese. And then continue from there to Europe/US. But I'm not even sure, that you need it. You can compete on western markets from China even without patenting your invention there just by the means of low prices (because of low manufacturing costs). That's why I think it is better to start in China and maybe even stop there. Maybe also patenting in India, Malasya, Indonesia afterwards within PCT. Does it makes sense?

Comment: You want patents either where others would  sell it or others would have it made. If the U.S. and the UK, for example, made up 80% of the market then getting a patent in China so it could not be made there and sold everywhere other than the U.S. and the UK might not be cost-effective. My view is to focus on the markets not the potential manufacturing sites.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite: taking your example - what prevents me from selling in U.S. and U.K. without a patent there? I do focus on those large markets but prevent competition not by means of a patent but by means of low price. And block others to manufacture cheaper by means of a patent in China. I wonder why it is not the standard approach... What is the problem with it... if any?... Maybe I don't understand your comment though...